# Key error 0 python in the objective function

Tags: python

My code in below giving a key error in the objective function and I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it. I would appreciate it if someone helps. The Key Error:0 in model.setObjective(quicksum(S[i] * X[i][t] for t in range(T) for i in range(N)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

```
from gurobipy import GRB,Model,quicksum
def Output(m):  
    # Print the result
    status_code = {1:'LOADED', 2:'OPTIMAL', 3:'INFEASIBLE', 4:'INF_OR_UNBD', 5:'UNBOUNDED'}
                                                                                            #is defined in Python
    status = m.status
    
    print('The optimization status is ' + status_code[status])
    if status == 2:    
        # Retrieve variables value
        print('Optimal solution:')
        for v in m.getVars():
            print(str(v.varName) + " = " + str(v.x))    
        print('Optimal objective value: ' + str(m.objVal) + "\n")
        
      
model=Model('project_scheduling')

#total number of projects
N=5
T=6
S=[220,210,250,240,380]
D=[2,4,3,3,4]
AB=[280,340,300,300,280,275]
C=[[57,96,0,0],
   [110,192,143,156],
   [155,129,119,0],
   [37,30,36,0],
   [108,81,89,65]]
X = model.addVars(N, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=["X_"+str(i)+","+str(t) for i in range (N) for t in range (T)]) 

model.setObjective(quicksum(S[i] * X[i][t] for t in range(T) for i in range(N)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

#CONSTRAINTS

model.addConstr(quicksum(X[i][t] for t in range(T)) <= 1 for i in range(N))

model.addConstr(quicksum(t * X[i][t] for t in range(T)) + D[i] <= T + 1 for i in range(N))

model.addConstr(X[0][0]==1)

model.addConstr(quicksum(X[2][t] for t in range(T)) >= quicksum(X[3][t] for t in range(T)))

model.addConstr(quicksum(t*X[3][t] for t in range(T)) + (T+1)*(1-quicksum(X[3][t] for t in range(T))) - quicksum(t*X[2][t] for t in range(T)) >= D[2]*quicksum(X[2][t] for t in range(T)))   

model.addConstr(quicksum(C[i][t+1-s]*X[i][s] for i in range(N) for s in range(T)) <= AB[t] for t in range(T))

#OPTIMIZATION
model.optimize()

Output(model)

model.write('project_scheduling.lp')
```

Comment: Where do you get the key error? Could you add the error to the question? Key error means that you try to access a key of a list or dictionary that doesn't exist in that particular dictionary. Maybe there is a typo in the key or that key is never set.

Comment: Thank you! The Key error:0 error is here: model.setObjective(quicksum(S[i] * X[i][t] for t in range(T) for i in range(N)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)